# Why Nilpotent Matrix is not Null matrix always?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence, cayley-hamilton, nilpotent-groups

I know it might sound dumb, but specifically, Why NULL matrices are not the only NULPOTENT matrices?
I am thinking that as all eigen values of NILPOTENT matrices are 0, then $\lambda = 0$, and as per Cayley-Hamilton theorem, when $\lambda =0$  then $A =0$  will also satisfy?

So instead of $A^n = 0$, because all eigen values are 0, thus, $A = 0$, also satisfies?

I know its wrong, but please point out where?

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton only says $A^n = 0$

Comment: Work some example.  You should easily be able to produce a $2\times 2$ real nilpotent matrix which is not $0$.

Comment: @SolubleFish but $lambda = 0 $ is a valid equation for nilpotent matrices, so $A = 0$, should also correspondingly satisfy? Here to move from lambda to A, I am using cayley-hamilton

Comment: Note that if $AB=0$, then this does not necessarily mean $A=B=0$ or $A=0$ while $B\neq 0$. It might occur that both $A$ and $B$ are non-zero matrices such that $AB=0$

Comment: It is important that you compute $A^2$ for Arthur's $2\times 2$-matrix yourself, so that you see exactly what is not correct with your argument. Take the eigenvalues of $A$, they are $0$ and $0$. Now apply Cayley-Hamilton as you wanted.

Comment: I sometimes find it helpful to think about what a nilpotent matrix does by thinking about the linear mapping it represents. This map takes the whole space to a proper subspace and then that subspace to a smaller one and so on until you get to zero.  In a sense, as well as mapping some null space to zero, the map also takes the rest of the space "closer" to that null space. Now if your imagination works (try it on Arthur's simple example) you should be able to see that this need not be done all in one step (as would be the case with the zero matrix).

Comment: I am new to this site, but know that downvote means bad question. Can you please also guide me on why its bad, so that I could improve it or learn how things work here

Comment: For starters, please don't use CAPS LOCK

Comment: @BhartenduKumar Thank you for : (a) using MathJax (b) Asking about what went wrong. I hope users here will be of help, your question has no issues apart from this, unless , if anything , perhaps seeing the comments you need to be more specific, since posts on this site already cover examples of non-zero matrices $A,B$ such that $AB = 0$, and thus we're unsure whether to redirect you there or have a further conversation, since from the point of view of eigenvalues you seem to be confused as to WHY eigenvalues aren't determining the matrix.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you so much! And yes I am comfortable in AB=0 singularity logics, and also the examples for Nilpotent matrices that are not Null matrices.   But, I am trying to see the flaw in , as $lambda = 0$ satisfies, then what cayley-hamilton I have done, I just substitute $ A =0$. But I think here is the problem, but not seeing exactly what

Comment: @BhartenduKumar The point is quite simple : $A=0$ will satisfy $A^n = 0$. But the other point is that that doesn't *imply* that $A=0$, because $A^n = 0$ could have other solutions. Let's take a simple example : if $x^2=1$, can I say $x=1$? No, right? Because we could have $x=-1$ as well. So something like that is happening here : we have an equation $A^n = 0$ and it has many solutions , *one* of which is $A=0$. That doesn't mean that $A$ can't be anything else : in fact, there are many other possibilities. So $A=0$ works, but many others also work : *why* they work, is because not every matrix

Comment: is characterized by its eigenvalue and eigenvector pairs : for some, there aren't enough eigenvectors to span the space. In particular, you can have unpredictable behaviour on the parts of the vector space which aren't decided by the eigenvectors. That's what leads to matrices whose $n$th powers are zero : they have less than $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Got it! Exactly this I was missing! Thank you so much! I know I cant accept the comment as correct answer, but I owe you gratitude!

Comment: @BhartenduKumar You are welcome! You can select the answer below which matches with my explanation the most, since I don't wish to add an answer mixing and matching those already present below. Thank you for the reception of my comments, and I wish you a good day on the site.

Comment: are symmetric Nilpotent matrices, always diagonalizable ? does this thing belong to this thread or should I ask new question?

Comment: @BhartenduKumar Use the search box , and use Google before asking a question on the site. I was informed many times that it's better to search for your answer on MSE and find one, rather than create a new question. For example, in this case, there's a famous result : "all symmetric matrices are diagonalizable". So not just symmetric nilpotent matrices, but *any* symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. In particular, however, that means that a symmetric nilpotent matrix must in fact equal the $0$ matrix! Perhaps you will like an explanation of the latter fact.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks! I knew somehow "all symmetric matrices are diagonalizable", but could not click. sorry. Yes Google search and MSE search I too think should be prerequisites but many times everything there, but visualization missing in LA for me. Got your answer, now having seen the whole circle. "Symmetric Nilpotent matrices are Null  always ".  Appreciate all the efforts!

Comment: @BhartenduKumar Good to have helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cayley-Hamilton says that the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$ of $A$ satistfies $\chi(A) = 0$. Since all eigenvalues of a nilpotent matrix are zero, we have :
  $$\chi_A (X) = \prod_{i} (X - \lambda_i) = X^n$$
  Therefore, $A^n = 0$. You cannot "move from $\lambda$ to $A$" if $A$ is not diagonalizable.
- If $A$ is diagonalizable, there is an invertible matrix $ P$ such that :
  $$ A = P \begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1 \\
  & \ddots \\
  && \lambda_n
  \end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$$
  If $A $ is nilpotent, we have $\lambda_1 = \ldots = \lambda_n =  0$. Therefore $A= 0$.

Comment: could you please guide me on how $  χA(X)=∏i(X−λi)=X^n$  gives characteristic equation. I have done only from $det(A - lambda I) = 0$, so please could you help

Comment: Any complex matrix is trigonalizable. By going to a basis where $A$ is upper triangular, the diagonal coefficient are the $\lambda_i$, so we see that $\det( XI_n - A ) = \prod_i (X-\lambda_i)$

Comment: If $X$ is the diagonal matrix obtained from elementary row operations of $A$, why $  det(XIn−A) $  is characteristic equation instead of $lambda$ in place of $X$

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is the (formal) polynomial $\chi(X) = \det(X I_n - A)$. The characteristic equation is then $\chi(\lambda)= 0$

Comment: Got it! $ X $ and $ lambda  $ did confusion! sorry. but what's the diagonalizable point, could you either explain or give link or add in your answer the diagonalizable theory please

Comment: Great I could visualize the whole thing!  Thank you so much

Comment: I am seeing that this similarity equation $ A = P .NULL. P^-1 $ has infinite possibilities for P, i.e. any invertible matrix of order n. Is this the case with only Null matrices, or are there other examples having more than one diagonalization possible?

Comment: First of all, you can always rescale $P \mapsto \lambda P$ for any non zero $\lambda$. Then, there is further liberty to choose $P$ when some of the eigenspaces have dimension $>1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124480/discussion-between-bhartendu-kumar-and-solublefish).

Answer (score 7):

Nilpotent matrices aren't necessarily zero because matrices like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
exist. Upper triangular matrices with zeroes on the diagonal are *always* nilpotent.

It is true that a *diagonalizable* nilpotent matrix must be the zero matrix, for reasons very similar to the eigen-argument you demonstrate. Such matrices are entirely determined by their eigenvectors and eigenvalues. However, non-diagonalizable matrices, like the one above, have too few eigenvectors to do this.

Comment: thank you @arthur. Though I think I am now clear on "why nilpotent does not mean null", but this diagonalizable logic and some matrices not be determined thing, I am new to. Please can you guide on how to learn that please or could you explain

Comment: @BhartenduKumar Just look at my example matrix, for example. It has a single eigenvector: $[1,0]^T$ (and scalings), with eigenvalue $0$. There is no way to use only that eigenvector to probe what the second column of the matrix is (we have $A[1,0]^T=[0,0]^T$, and nothing more, and that doesn't let us solve for the two right-side entries of the matrix). You need more. And what you need is called diagonalizable. A matrix is diagonalizable iff it has enough eigenvectors to solve for the entire matrix this way (that's not the actual definition of diagonalizable, but it's close enough for now).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a $n \times n$ nilpotent matrix $A.$ Then its characteristics equation is $ \lambda ^n.$  Now, the minimal polynomial of the matrix $A$ could be $ \lambda ^k$ for any $ 1 \leq k \leq n$ ( the equation of the minimal polynomial depends on the matrix). The matrix is $0$ if $k =1$, and for the rest of the values of $k$ we will have a non-zero nilpotent matrix. For reference, you can take a look at Jordan normal form of a matrix.

As an example of non-zero nilpotent matrix, take any strictly upper triangular matrix. One such matrix is mentioned in some of the answers.

Comment: thank you so much! this answer has all the needed theory for this question. It helped